# Can i use android studio to write libgdx games?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying out libgdx for the first time. My game is only going to be made for android.Can i use android studio to write libgdx games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Android Studio for libgdx projects.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

Answer (score 0):

You "can" use android studio for libgdx projects, but I personally would use IntelliJ IDE.  It is the base for what Android Studio is built from but is more suited for Java specific applications.  Android Studio will do the job, but is being tailored more towards android specific development.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

Download the package builder and create a gradle project to import into IntelliJ.
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html